deploy logic app workflow using azapi_resource
Is it possible to upload the definition? like this workflow.json is in a separate file download from Azure portal designer. I want to use this resource to automatize process via IaC so to upload workflow that is previously manually defined in Azure logic app portal
  resource "azapi_resource" "logic_app_workflow_upload" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01"
  name      = var.workflow_name
  location  = var.location
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group_name.id
  depends_on = [azurerm_api_connection.teams-api-connection]

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.logic_app_identity.id]
  }

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      definition = jsondecode(data.local_file.logicapp_workflow_definition.content)
      parameters = {
        "$connections" = {
          value = {
            teams = {
              connectionId   = azurerm_api_connection.teams-api-connection.id
              connectionName = azurerm_api_connection.teams-api-connection.name
              id             = azurerm_api_connection.teams-api-connection.managed_api_id
              teamsUri       = var.teams_uri
              channelId      = var.teams_channel_id
              groupId        = var.teams_group_id
              containername  = var.storage_container_name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

